# How do you update apis in real time?

Tags: node.js, api, rest

So I’ve been looking for tutorials on how to update a RESTful api every day automatically. I want the data to change each day, so is there a way to do this using node.js?

(No code provided because I want to create a new api)

Comment: Are you looking for something like `cron`?

Comment: Wait lemme give an example. Say a weather api updates every day or more frequently so how can I do that with my api?

Comment: A weather API likely doesn't need to 'do an update' at a fixed interval. It's more likely some other system triggers the updates as the information comes in.

Comment: Do you know what that system could be @Evert ? I want to implement it into my api so it updates every day

Comment: 'Something that updates something else based on some action' can be anything in the world. It's not something specific. If you want to fire 'some script' as a fixed time a day, the default tool for this is `cron`.

Comment: If that's not helpful, try to expand more on your specific situatin, what you tried... why `cron` doesn't work or you, etc...